# How to render animation of a spheres inside a cube? After rendering i see only cube please help me out

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation

I added few spheres in a cube. What should I do to see all objects after rendering[image]
Sorry for bad image.

Comment: I am trying to make animation of electrons moving between a metal bar. But when I render it shows only the bar

Comment: if your cubes are opaque, how could we see the spheres?

Comment: 1. there is a screenshot function in windows. Snipping tool. 2. you're displaying the bar as wired, but it's getting rendered in solid. Uncheck camera visibility in cycles for the bar.

Comment: Please use https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ for clearer screenshots. Thanks.